# static library from Fortran Modules

Tags: module, fortran

I am not a very expert Fortran programmer, but now that I have written many subroutines (in Fortran 90), I have to put them in Modules (employed by "use" statement in other subroutines and program) to avoid writing the interfaces. I have to use these modules with old code written in F77.
I don't want the compiler to compile these modules again and again. So I created a static library from the ".o" files after compiling these modules:

`ar rc libmymath.a module1.o module2.o module3.o`

However I still need to keep the ".mod" files of these modules to be able to "use" them in my code.

**My question:** is it possible to pack these ".mod" files in the static library archive ".a" (as we did with .o files), so that everything is encapsulated in the single file static library?

P.S: by anywhere I mean across my systems, all of them use gfortran 64 bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

In an analogue to C/C++, a `.mod` file is like a header file. It describes the contents of the module and the `USE <module>` is similar to the `#include <header>`.

These mod files are compiler (and often even version) specific and are required because modules name-mangle the functions and so there needs to be a lookup table for the resulting function names.

Comment: Thank you very much. This analogy is very helpful in understanding the way '.mod' files are used in Fortran.

Comment: Is there any easy way to handle these '.mod' files? 
I have many modules, and each module contains many functions and subroutines for specific calculations.
So it is not desirable to reduce number of modules by increasing number of subroutines/functions per module.

Comment: How you handle them depends on your build system really. We use CMake and have it install all the mod files into an include directory, just like you would header files. So our codes install into a `/bin`, `/lib` and `/include` directory structure. But otherwise, it's just like handling a bunch of header files and organization is up to you, and how you implement the organization depends on your build system.

Comment: Now I have another problem ! I have built the library from modules compiled by `gfortran`. I sent these libraries to a colleague who has AMD's Open64 (OpenF90) compiler. So when he tried to used this static library with his code, using OpenF90, he got error about missing `.mod` files (Open64 uses upper case alphabets for naming `.mod` files). Is there any method to tell Open64 that these `.mod` files have names written in lower case alphabets?

Comment: Unfortunately, `.mod` files are not compatible with other compilers typically. In fact, they often aren't even compatible with different versions of the same compiler. The analogy to header files falls apart when you need to look at multiple compilers. Because the way compilers name-mangle isn't part of the Fortran standard, the format for `.mod` files is also not standardized. In fact, gfortran mod files are plain text while ifort (Intel) mod files are in binary.

Answer (score 3):

You just copy those `.mod files` to your `fortran finclude directory`.

e.g I am using `ubuntu` with `gcc -4.4.3`. What i did is I have copied the library `librandom.a` to `/usr/local/lib` and the mod file `random.mod` to `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/finclude`.

Now I don't have to create those mods again and again . I just have to use `gfortran -o myfile myfile.f90 -lrandom` to compile my program and link with the library. Of course i have to use "use random " in my myfile.f90.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to compile with

`gfortran myprog.f90  -I/path/to/mod_files -L /path/to/lib -lmylib`

where the `module.mod` are in the directory `/path/to/mod_files`. The `module.o` was generated by

`gfortran -c /path/to/mod_files/module.f90`

and the library `mylib.a` was generated  by

`ar rcv /path/to/lib/mylib.a /path/to/mod_files/module.o`

But you still have to keep the .mod files.

I had this same issue.

I hope I have helped.